# How do you run the maven-gae-plugin "mvn gae:run" command from inside Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, maven-gae-plugin

From the command line, the [maven-gae-plugin](http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/plugin-info.html) can be run by calling:

```
mvn gae:run
```

I am working in a [Maven project](http://github.com/tleese22/google-app-engine-jappstart) with a [POM file](http://github.com/tleese22/google-app-engine-jappstart/blob/master/pom.xml) that declares the use of the maven-gae-plugin.

I can run this maven command from the command-line in Windows. But, after setting up the source code as a project inside Eclipse, I don't know how to run this command from inside the Eclipse IDE. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using m2eclipse, **right-click** on your Maven project, go to **Run As** → **Maven Build…** and create your **Run Configuration** for a **Maven Build**. Here is an example:

[image]

This configuration would run the `gae:run` goal on the selected project.

To access it later, **right-click** on a Maven project and go to **Run As** → **Maven Build** (without the **…**), then select the launch configuration.